# Line rasterizing algorithm - Rewriting inequations

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the rasterizing algorithm for curves (but also straight lines) described in this paper  http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/Bresenham.pdf

The general approach is described on page 10 and 11, here is an excerpt

> ## 1.4 General Solution
>
> An error e of the pixel p is introduced by the algorithm as a
>   measurement for the deviation of the pixel from the curve: e = f(x,y).
>   The error value is zero for pixels exactly at the curve, positive for
>   one side and negative for the other side of the curve. This error
>   calculation is used for the decision which pixel should be set next. 
>   Starting by
>   pixel p only between three possible pixel could be chosen for the next
>   pixel because of the positive gradient: $P_{x}$ or $P_{xy}$. The algorithm
>   starts with the assumption that point $P_{xy}$ will be set next. So if the
>   error $\lvert e_{xy}\rvert$ of point $P_{xy}$ is lesser than the error $\lvert e_{x}\rvert$ of pixel $P_{x}$
>   than the x direction will be incremented. The same decision is
>   considered for the y direction. If the error $\lvert e_{xy}\rvert$ of 
>   $P_{xy}$ is lesser
>   than the error $\lvert e_{y}\rvert$ than the y direction will be incremented.

So I would translate that into the following conditions

if $ \lvert e_{xy}\rvert <  \lvert e_{x}\rvert$ then increment x

if $ \lvert e_{xy}\rvert <  \lvert e_{y}\rvert$ then increment y

Then it continues

> ... Since a positive gradient is assumed and the error on one
>   side of the curve will be negative, the unequation $e_{x} ≥ e_{xy} ≥ e_{y}$ will
>   always be true which makes it possible to avoid the calculation of the
>   absolute value for the comparison.
>
> The conditions for the increments
>   are now:
>
> if $e_{x} + e_{xy} > 0$ then increment x
>
> if $e_{y} + e_{xy} < 0$ then increment y

I have trouble understanding how these last two inequations are derived from the previous described ones.

Thanks for helping

Comment: how do you draw a  line of pixels from $(0,0)$ to $(p,q)$ without divisions ? (assuming $p \ge q$)

Comment: I would use Bresenhams line algorithm with integer only arithmetic

Comment: then it's ok, you understood bresenham, where is the problem ? adapting it to draw a circle or a quadratic is a little harder but the principle are the same

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not phrase my question clearly enough. I am trying to understand how the inequations with absolute values are transformed into the ones at the end of the quote.